# Uniform convergence in complex domain

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I know how to prove $(1+x/n)^n \to e^x$ uniformly if $x \in [a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$  by finding a uniform bound $e^x - (1 +x/n)^n < K/n$ for a bounded interval.

My question is how to prove the $(1 + z/n)^n \to e^z$ on any compact set $S \subset \mathbb{C}$.  I am not sure how to extend from the real case in the proof.

Comment: If you have defined $e^{z} $ via the series $\sum z^n/n! $ then the proof for the real case applies to the complex case also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let Log denote the principal branch of logarithm. Then $\frac {Log (1+z)} z \to 1$ as $z \to 0$. Let $\epsilon >0$. There exists $\delta >0$ such that $|\frac {Log (1+z)} z -1| < \epsilon$ if $|z| <\delta$. Let K be a compact set in $\mathbb  C$. Then $|n \frac {Log (1+z/n)} z -1| <\epsilon$ for all $z \in K$ provided n is sufficiently large. [ Because $|\frac z n|<\delta$ if $z \in K$ and n is sufficiently large]. Hence $ |{Log \{(1+z/n)^{n}\}} -z| <\epsilon |z|$ By continuity of the exponential function at 0 this proves that$(1+z/n)^{n} e^{-z} \to 1$ uniformly on K. Finally, $|(1+z/n)^{n}-e^{z}| \leq |(1+z/n)^{n} e^{-z}-1| e^{|z|} \to 0$ uniformly on K.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose the missing details can be filled with (1) the first limit is $1$ using power series and (2) sufficiently large $n$ is independent of $z$ since $|z| < B$ for all $z \in K$.

Comment: You are right. Sorry that I left out some easy steps.